# Android. Values are not assigned

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android application which is not working properly.
The app runs, but in the final calculation, the value of each level is not recognized. The program does not indicate to me any error. I can't understand what could be wrong.

Here's the .Java File

```
    package com.com.calculartmb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // variaveis

    double altura;
    double peso;
    double resultado;
    double nivel;

    EditText pesoEd;
    EditText alturaEd;
    EditText finalEd;

    SeekBar altSeekBar;
    SeekBar pesoSeekBar;

    RadioButton radio1;
    RadioButton radio2;
    RadioButton radio3;
    RadioButton radio4;
    RadioButton radio5;
    RadioGroup radioGrupo;

    private double[] checklistValues = new double[6];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // iniciação
        pesoEd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        alturaEd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        finalEd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        altSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        pesoSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);

        radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        radio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        radio4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4);
        radio5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio5);
        radioGrupo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        altSeekBar.setMax(25000);
        pesoSeekBar.setMax(60000);


        //listeners
        addChangeListenerToRadios();
        altSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(altSeekBarListener);
        pesoSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(pesoSeekBarListener);

    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener pesoSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Calcula o novo valor do TIP
            peso = (pesoSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;
            // mostra na caixa o valor novo
            pesoEd.setText(String.format("%.02f", peso).replace(',', '.'));
            // Chama o update
            updateValorTMB();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener altSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Calcula o novo valor do TIP
            altura = (altSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;
            // mostra na caixa o valor novo
            alturaEd.setText(String.format("%.02f", altura).replace(',', '.'));
            // Chama o update
            updateValorTMB();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    private void updateValorTMB() {

        double peso = Double.parseDouble(pesoEd.getText().toString());

        double altura = Double.parseDouble(alturaEd.getText().toString());

        double resultado = 655 + (9.6 * peso) + (1.8 * altura) - (4.7 * nivel);


        finalEd.setText(String.format("%.02f", resultado));

    }



    public void addChangeListenerToRadios(){

        radioGrupo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){


            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checklistValues[0] = (radio1.isChecked())?1.2:0;
                checklistValues[1] = (radio2.isChecked())?1.37:0;
                checklistValues[2] = (radio3.isChecked())?1.65:0;
                checklistValues[3] = (radio4.isChecked())?1.72:0;
                checklistValues[4] = (radio5.isChecked())?1.9:0;

                setNivelFromChecklist();

                updateValorTMB();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }

    private void setNivelFromChecklist(){

        double total= 0;

        for (double item:checklistValues){

            total += item; 
        }

        nivel = total * .01;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

It's giving me the warning that the yeallow ine it's not being used.

[image]

And here's the LogCat. Because the app can run anyway.

```
?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
03-10 15:50:37.119: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 15:56:17.109: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 453K, 14% free 3367K/3892K, paused 253ms, total 272ms
03-10 16:00:01.739: D/ConnectivityService(374): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-10 16:00:02.519: D/ConnectivityService(374): Done.
03-10 16:00:02.519: D/ConnectivityService(374): Setting timer for 720seconds
03-10 16:14:00.259: I/ProcessStatsService(374): Prepared write state in 139ms
03-10 16:15:00.139: I/ActivityManager(374): Killing 560:com.android.printspooler/u0a38 (adj 15): empty for 1846s
03-10 16:15:01.689: D/ConnectivityService(374): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-10 16:15:02.319: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 660K, 13% free 5786K/6648K, paused 525ms, total 528ms
03-10 16:15:02.479: D/ConnectivityService(374): Done.
03-10 16:15:02.489: D/ConnectivityService(374): Setting timer for 720seconds
03-10 16:15:02.969: D/MobileDataStateTracker(374): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-10 16:16:00.049: I/ActivityManager(374): Killing 991:com.android.keychain/1000 (adj 15): empty for 1814s
03-10 16:16:00.129: I/ActivityManager(374): Killing 451:android.process.media/u0a4 (adj 15): empty for 1815s
03-10 16:16:00.139: I/ActivityManager(374): Killing 834:com.android.music/u0a31 (adj 15): empty for 1834s
03-10 16:16:00.179: I/ActivityManager(374): Killing 620:com.android.defcontainer/u0a3 (adj 15): empty for 1836s
03-10 16:16:00.899: W/MediaFocusControl(374):   RemoteControlClient died
03-10 16:17:48.239: D/dalvikvm(425): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1392K, 67% free 4302K/12768K, paused 331ms, total 333ms
03-10 16:18:10.359: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 563K, 17% free 3317K/3952K, paused 330ms, total 341ms
03-10 16:29:26.989: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 105 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 16:30:01.149: D/ConnectivityService(374): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-10 16:30:01.399: D/ConnectivityService(374): Done.
03-10 16:30:01.459: D/ConnectivityService(374): Setting timer for 720seconds
03-10 16:30:49.609: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 16:37:00.289: I/Choreographer(425): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 16:39:14.209: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 16:40:11.109: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 17% free 3318K/3952K, paused 376ms, total 376ms
03-10 16:40:12.779: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 16:40:34.109: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 16:41:49.109: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 16:44:00.599: I/ProcessStatsService(374): Prepared write state in 148ms
03-10 16:45:01.589: D/ConnectivityService(374): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-10 16:45:01.859: D/ConnectivityService(374): Done.
03-10 16:45:01.889: D/ConnectivityService(374): Setting timer for 720seconds
03-10 16:45:02.599: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 748K, 13% free 5789K/6648K, paused 408ms, total 409ms
03-10 16:45:02.659: E/NetdConnector(374): NDC Command {58 bandwidth gettetherstats} took too long (810ms)
03-10 16:45:02.799: D/MobileDataStateTracker(374): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-10 16:45:02.899: V/BackupManagerService(374): Running a backup pass
03-10 16:45:03.159: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(509): Dictionary info: dictionary = UserHistoryDictionary.en_US.dic ; version = ? ; date = 1394484303
03-10 16:45:03.169: V/BackupManagerService(374): clearing pending backups
03-10 16:45:03.239: V/PerformBackupTask(374): Beginning backup of 6 targets
03-10 16:45:03.239: I/PerformBackupTask(374): Initializing (wiping) backup state and transport storage
03-10 16:45:03.289: D/BackupManagerService(374): Now staging backup of android
03-10 16:45:03.319: D/BackupManagerService(374): Now staging backup of com.android.providers.settings
03-10 16:45:03.329: D/BackupManagerService(374): Now staging backup of com.android.providers.userdictionary
03-10 16:45:03.349: D/BackupManagerService(374): Now staging backup of com.android.sharedstoragebackup
03-10 16:45:03.369: D/BackupManagerService(374): Now staging backup of com.android.browser
03-10 16:45:03.399: D/BackupManagerService(374): Now staging backup of com.android.calendar
03-10 16:45:03.439: V/LocalTransport(374): wiping all data
03-10 16:45:03.559: D/PerformBackupTask(374): invokeAgentForBackup on @pm@
03-10 16:45:03.569: E/PerformBackupTask(374): Error invoking for backup on @pm@
03-10 16:45:03.619: I/PerformBackupTask(374): Backup pass finished.
03-10 16:45:03.629: E/PerformBackupTask(374): Duplicate finish
03-10 16:46:28.229: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 17:00:01.289: D/ConnectivityService(374): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-10 17:00:01.649: D/ConnectivityService(374): Done.
03-10 17:00:01.769: D/ConnectivityService(374): Setting timer for 720seconds
03-10 17:01:05.979: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 17:02:16.129: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 17% free 3317K/3952K, paused 293ms, total 297ms
03-10 17:06:00.589: D/dalvikvm(425): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 538K, 67% free 4276K/12768K, paused 194ms, total 200ms
03-10 17:15:00.139: I/ProcessStatsService(374): Prepared write state in 53ms
03-10 17:15:01.669: D/ConnectivityService(374): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-10 17:15:02.319: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 750K, 13% free 5785K/6648K, paused 550ms, total 555ms
03-10 17:15:02.449: D/ConnectivityService(374): Done.
03-10 17:15:02.449: D/ConnectivityService(374): Setting timer for 720seconds
03-10 17:15:03.139: D/MobileDataStateTracker(374): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-10 17:15:39.759: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 17:20:46.539: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 17:24:09.389: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 17% free 3317K/3952K, paused 257ms, total 263ms
03-10 17:26:26.869: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 17:30:01.339: D/ConnectivityService(374): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-10 17:30:01.489: D/ConnectivityService(374): Done.
03-10 17:30:01.489: D/ConnectivityService(374): Setting timer for 720seconds
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the warning? It doesn't make any sense and the more likely warning would be that the method is missing an `@Override` annotation. I suspect that the warning has nothing to do with the app not behaving properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `new OnCheckedChangeListener` you have there, it has included an `@Override` method which you should be using, rather than your own implementation;

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        }
```

Try to move your `checkListValues` code from your method to the one provided.